# Installing suggested packages only by top-level listed packages rather than dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

If I do the following:

```
apt install SomePackage --install-suggests
```

It will try and not just install suggested packages specified by `SomePackage`, but also those packages listed as suggestions by any packages `SomePackage` depends on if said dependencies aren't already installed.

Is there a way to tell apt to install packages suggested by only those I have explicitly listed but not those that fall further down the dependency tree?

Answer (score 1):

There are three sorts of dependencies:

- **Depends**. These must be pulled in, and for good reason. You can prevent these by using and apt flag that I won't discuss here because it's dangerous and likely to break whatever you are trying to install.
- **Recommends**. These should be pulled in for a full feature set. In Ubuntu, this is **enabled** by default. You can turn it off with apt's `--no-install-recommends` flag or change the apt configuration item `APT::Install-Recommends` from '1' to '0'. Most users should never need to touch this setting. You can check the current setting with `apt-config dump | grep Install-Recommends`
- **Suggests**. These can be pulled in under limited circumstances to supplement functionality. In Ubuntu, this is **disabled** by default. You can turn it on with apt's `--install-suggests` flag or change the apt configuration item `APT::Install-Suggests` from '0' to '1'. Most users should never need to touch this setting. You can check the current setting with `apt-config dump | grep Install-Suggests`

Apt will follow the dependency tree all the way with the same settings. There is no way to change the settings halfway down the tree.

If you want some (but not all) suggested packages, you must list the packages you want. This may complicate your future life: Manually-specified packages are not eligible for autoremove, so you will need to clean up manually, too. Take good notes.

Answer (score 1):

this functionality is still **broken** (not behaving as users want or as manual describes), and i miss this in every single distro except Arch.

- In the frontends, i get first level suggestions automatically only in
  Manjaro's Pamac. Without any effort. Additionally I can browse suggests or depends extremely easy.
  In Discover,
  Muon, Yast etc I hardly get a list of suggests in a text format,
  without possibility to copy. None of them show installed files before installation. It's rather unbelievable. In Synaptic, you can right-click to choose suggested packages, but only only one by one.
- Now in CLI, apt really suggest gigabytes of **unwanted** packages. To fix:

> apt install SomePackage $(apt-cache depends SomePackage|grep Suggests:|grep -v "<"|cut -d' ' -f4)